# How to retrieve file contents to upload in API? Solved

Tags: java, http, post, file-upload, http-post

I'm stuck in a problem of trying to upload something with a File parameter...

I had the idea of acquiring the string of the file, but I realized that I need to acquire the file's contents. How do you retrieve the file contents and upload it to the designated site?

EDIT: Managed to find problem

Here's the solution:

```
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        try {
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://api.teknik.io/upload/post");

            FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File("C:/Users/hp/Desktop/hid.txt"));

            HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addPart("file", bin).build();


            httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

            System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                if (resEntity != null) {
                    System.out.println("Response content length: " + resEntity.getContentLength());
                }
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
                EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
```

It returns:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Response content length: 119
[{"results":
{"file":{"name":"rB8mlB.txt","url":"https://u.teknik.io/rB8mlB.txt","type":"inode/x-empty","size":0}}}]

I managed to make it work on a pdf file, but txt files are problematic
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Response content length: 126
[{"results":{"file":{"name":"RfWjkg.pdf","url":"https://u.teknik.io/RfWjkg.pdf","type":"application/pdf","size":341852}}}]

Answer (score 0):

use MultipartRequest jar file.

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.oreilly.servlet.*;
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet
{

public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException , ServletException
{
    res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
    MultipartRequest mpr=new MultipartRequest(req,getServletContext().getRealPath("file"),500*1024*1024);
    out.println("<html><body><h3>File Uploaded<h3></html></body>");
}
}
```

call this servlet on upload button.